# Allow implementing classes to use themselves as types

Tags: c#

I am just wandering if the following is possible in C#.

Let's say I have a List-like interface that mandates the operation `reverse`. I.e.:

```
public interface ReversableList<T> {
      // Return a copy of this list but reversed
      ReversableList<T> Reverse();

      // We still need to return the contained type sometimes
      T Get(int index)
}
```

However, now when I go and implement that interface:

```
public class ListImplementation<T> : ReversableList<T> 
      ReversableList<T> Reverse();   
}
```

I am still forced to use the interface `ReversableList`. So even if the user were to instantiate my `ListImplementation` directly, they are still forced to deal with `ReversableList` when calling the `Reverse` method:

```
var concreteList = new ListImplementation<String>();
ReversableList<T> reversed = concreteList.Reverse();
```

whereas what I had in mind was that `Reverse()` of the `ListImplementation` will be another `ListImplementation`, like so:

```
var concreteList = new ListImplementation<String>();
ListImplementation<String> reversed = concreteList.Reverse();
```

while still implementing a generic enough interface.

*If this is confusing, let me know and I will clarify/add any necessary details or corrections. Thank you!*

### Source of interest

*What follows is the explanation for why this is interesting to me.*

I followed the function called `reversed` in the [scala's collections](http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml) from the `List` (which is a concrete type) through all the interfaces (traits) that it inherits.

What I found is very curious.

The original `reverse` method is defined abstractly on the [`GenSeqLike` trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenSeqLike.html).

```
trait GenSeqLike[+A, +Repr] ...
    def reverse: Repr   // <--- NO BODY, means abstract
```

Then, it is defined *concretely* in a [trait SeqLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html) that extends `GenSeqLike` trait:

```
trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr] extends GenSeqLike[A, Repr]
    def reverse: Repr
        //iterates through this seqence
        // and reverses 
        for (x <- this)
           //...etc
```

Then, what is interesting, is that the next two traits:

```
trait Seq[+A] extends SeqLike[A, Seq[A]]   //<-- NOTE here is the type for "Repr"
     //no mention of reverse

trait LinearSeq[+A] extends Seq[A] with SeqLike[A, Seq[A]] //<-- NOTE type again
    // no mention of reverse
```

both get a "free" version of the `reverse` function, but both of them work in terms of their respective "interfaces" (traits). So `reverse` on `Seq` returns a `Seq`.

Finally, the `List` concrete class implements the `LinearSeq` trait and redefines the `reverse` method (for efficiency purposes I assume).

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends LinearSeq[A]
                                 with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]] 

      override def reverse: List[A] = {
          //faster impl without foreach iteration
          ...
      }
```

where the `LinearSeqOptimized` is simply another "chain" of traits that goes all the way up to `SeqLike[A, Repr]`.

So you can see, how a generic "interface" was used to specify some "behavior", how an intermediate "interface" provided some kind of "default" implementation, and how all the sub-"interfaces" and subtypes all reaped the benefit of that implementation while preserving the return types to be of their "own" types. Phew. Confusing, I know!

Comment: Abstract class would not be my first choice for api design, but maybe I'll try it out in C#...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it should be the first choice, merely a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: At least you may `ListImplementation<String> impl = (ListImplementation<String>)concreteList.Reverse();`

Comment: @MitchWheat I appreciate that suggestion. One problem I see with this approach is being limited to single abstract class, whereas one could implement many interfaces.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Yes, but down-casting is, I believe, harmful to performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way, although it can be a bit tricky.

Change the `ReversableList` interface to this:

```
public interface ReversableList<L, T> where L : ReversableList<L, T>
{
    // Return a copy of this list but reversed
    L Reverse();
}
```

Now you implement it like this:

```
public class ListImplementation<T> : ReversableList<ListImplementation<T>, T>
{
    public ListImplementation<T> Reverse() { /* code */ }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing it the same way. I don't know if I need  that constraint on `L` though.

Comment: @drozzy - It's advisable to include the constraint as it helps you to do the implementation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
public interface IReversableList<T> where T : IReversableList<T>
{
    // Return a copy of this list but reversed 
    T Reverse();
}

public class ListImplementation<T> : IReversableList<ListImplementation<T>>
{
    public ListImplementation<T> Reverse()
    {
        return new ListImplementation<T>();
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as

```
var concreteList = new ListImplementation<string>();
ListImplementation<string> reversed = concreteList.Reverse();
```

**EDIT**

Added the constraint on the interface.

Comment: This is a bit whacky as you would expect `IReversableList<T>` to be a list of items of type `T` rather than the concrete implementation of a list of `T`. Very confusing and not in keeping with the other .NET list interfaces.

Comment: I agree with @Enigmativity in that `IReversableList` should be typed by the items which it contains. This is because aside from `reverse` function, it may have functions like `T Get(int index)` where `T` in this case should be the type of the item stored in the list. I am sorry for explaining it poorly in my question. I'll make an adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

This particular case is already handled by the Enumerable extensions: [Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)

```
 var list = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
 list.Reverse();
```

Not an answer to this question, but maybe help to a searcher in the future!

Comment: Great idea. There is still a problem that if you have an interface inherit from `IFoo : IEnumerable`, and then call the `Reverse` method on that type, it will return `IEnumerable`: i.e.: `IEnumerable<T> x = FooImpl().Reverse()`, and not `IFoo`.